# Flex embedding an image where the path is based on a bound variable

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to embed an image using an item renderer in my Flex project.

The image path however is a String passed in as a bound variable.

I am aware that

```
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('/../assets/image.png')" />
```

works because the image is embedded at runtime? (Could someone please clarify this)

How would i go about embedding my bound string, somewhat like this:

```
<s:BitmapImage source="@Embed('/../assets/{data.image}')" />
```

Many Thanks

Comment: The first example with a static (non-variable) path works because it is done at **compile** time, not run time. To embed something the path must be known at compile time for the object to be physically included in the compiled SWF. If the path is not known at compile time, you cannot embed it. I'd give this as the answer, but since it's possible to generate Actionscript byte code dynamically at run time, maybe someone has a nifty way of doing what you're looking for. If the path is not known till runtime, and there may be many possible images, I don't think embedding is a good approach :)

Comment: That would be impressive to see but certainly a heavy-handed approach for dynamically finding an image path.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better choice if you'd like to embed the image but find it dynamically at runtime is: Embed all of the images it could be and then grab a reference to it dynamically.  We generally use a pattern like this:

```
public class Icons {
    [Embed(source="icons/icon1.png")]
    public var icon1:Class;
    [Embed(source="icons/icon2.png")]
    public var icon2:Class;
}
```

Then you can dynamically grab the embedded images from your Icons instance at run-time.

**Edit - self contained example** - I'll use an item renderer since I think that's what you're doing.
Let's assume `data.image` can be 'plane' 'train' or 'automobile'

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Embed(source="/assets/icons/plane.png")]
            public var plane : Class;
            [Embed(source="/assets/icons/train.png")]
            public var train : Class;
            [Embed(source="/assets/icons/automobile.png")]
            public var automobile : Class;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Image source="{this[data.image]}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

This is a really simple example and not the BEST way to implement, but you get the idea.

Comment: I have seen snippets of code that look somewhat similar during my research - could you clarify a little more on how this works?

Comment: sure - let's say you implement the Icons class a Singleton.  It looks like you're storing the name of the image in your model object in the "image" proprety.  So let's say instead of setting "image" to icon1.png, you just set it to icon1.  Then you could do something like `<s:BitmapImage source="{Icons.getInstance()[data.image]"/>`  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have got it working by making the item renderer view be based off a class which instantiates a new Icons instance. I then call {icons[data.image]} (where icons is the name of my var).

Your implementation using getInstance was throwing up errors - it did not know what Icons was etc.

Although it works I have two warnings: "Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "icons"" and "Data binding will not be able to detect changes when using square bracket operator.  For Array, please use"

Being somewhat new to AS I am still a little unsure of how I got my result.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like embed icons with css files. Then in ItemRenderer you can set css class and get image which you want.

css file or mxml css block:

```
.icons 
{
    bender: Embed(source="/assets/bender.png");
    /* other icons */
}
```

In renderer, when you override set data method:

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value;

    var iconName:String = data.image;

    if ( iconName )
    {
        var cssDecl2:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration(".icons");
        var IconClass:Class = cssDecl2.getStyle( iconName );
        bmImage.source = new IconClass();
    }
}
```

and bmImage as id s:BitmapImage:

```
<s:BitmapImage id="bmImage" />
```